# Is it possible to read Excel data from a Powerpoint Add-in?

Tags: office-js, office-addins

I'm just beginning to work with Office Add-ins. I started to code some simple add-ins.

I would like now to create a Powerpoint slide, and create shapes based on external data. I'm free to define the external data format. Could be a text file, or CSV, but ideally data in an Excel spreadsheet.

Assuming the add-in is developed for Powerpoint, Office.context.document accesses the current Powerpoint document.

Now, does it exist another OfficeJS object/property/function/etc which can access, from this Powerpoint-hosted add-in, an Excel file, and read the data that it contains?
Please note, the objective is to remain in the Office Add-in technology. That is, avoiding ASP .Net, Office Dev tools Visual Studio based, etc., if possible.

Although I Googled and browse the available Office Add-ins doc, I could not find any useful pointer.

Any help appreciated.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Office.js doesn't have its own API for getting data from another Office document, but JavaScript in the PowerPoint add-in can [use Microsoft Graph to get data from an Excel spreadsheet](https://learn.microsoft.com/graph/excel-concept-overview), provided that it is stored in OneNote or SharePoint.